# Compiled with JDK1.7, run in JRE 1.8: possible to install security patches?

Tags: java, linux, javac

If I compiled my program using JDK1.7 and on a Linux server it uses JRE1.8, is it then still possible to have the security patches (public updates) provided by Oracle? By public updates I mean "Java SE Public Updates": http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/eol-135779.html

Comment: unless you're building some huge monolithic executable that embeds the JVM itself, you'd just be using whatever jvm is on the system running your app, meaning it'd get whatever patches the system operator chooses (allows?) to be installed.

Comment: What exactly are you asking? What does your program being compiled in JDK 1.7 have to do with public updates? JRE 1.8 will get the updates, as long as you install them, until Oracle decides not to support it any longer, which is the case with 1.7.

Comment: so the public updates have nothing to do with the JDK? So even if you compiled your program in Java 1.4 and run it in JRE1.8 you'll still have the security patches?

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18364418/is-java-byte-code-compiled-in-jdk-6-and-runs-on-jdk7-open-to-vulnerability-fixed). Basically, only if the vulnerability would be in the compiler (which I'm not sure has ever happened?) the stuff you use won't matter, only the environment you use for running.

Answer (score 0):

You will continue to get the update support or more precisely the public updates for Java 8 as long as they intend to provide.As your server is running java SE8, You would not have any issues. Anyways, you could recompile your program in java 8. No Issues with that.